# How to copy text from pdf file to text file without keeping original format

Tags: r

I have a pdf file that I want to extract text from. However, I do not want to keep the same spacing of the pdf file. I want the text to appear as if I copied and pasted the lines from the pdf manually. This would some remove some aesthetic, but unnecessary tabs and spacing complications from my text file.

For example, if I extract the text normally, using R, I would get a format similar to this:

```
                             This is the title
                             of this document
1.0 Hello my name is John and blah balh blah blah blah.
        1.1 blah blah blah blah
```

If I just manually copy and paste, I would get something similar to:

```
This is the title of this document
1.0 Hello my name is John and blah balh blah blah blah.
1.1 blah blah blah blah blah
```

I was wondering if there was any way to do this through code in R instead of just manually copying and pasting.

A real example of this is the pdf: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/James_Hamilton11/publication/24108242_Oil_and_the_Macroeconomy_since_World_War_II/links/0c9605252c0916e709000000.pdf

If I were to copy and paste manually part of page 228 or the 3rd page in the pdf,
I would get:

```
Oil and the Macroeconomy since World War 11
James D. Hamilton
University (f/' Virgiiwa
All but one of the U.S. recessions since World War II have been
preceded, typically with a lag of around three-fourths of a year, by a
dramatic increase in the price of crude petroleum. This does not
mean that oil shocks caused these recessions. Evidence is presented,
however, that even over the period 1948-72 this correlation is statistically
significant and nonspurlious, supporting the proposition that
oil shocks were a contributing factor in at least some of the U.S.
recessions prior to 1972. By extension, energy price increases may
account for much of post-OPEC macroeconomic performance.
I. Introduction
The poor performance of the U.S. economy since 1973 is well documented:

1. The rate of growth of real GNP has fallen from an average of
4.0 percent during 1960-72 to 2.4 percent for 1973-81.
2. The 7.6 percent average inflation rate during 1973-81 was
more than double the 3.1 percent realized for 1960-72.
3. The average unemployment rate over 1973-81 of 6.7 percent
was higher than in any year between 1948 and 1972 with the single
exception of the recession of 1958.
This paper is drawn from chap. 2 of my Ph.D. dissertation at the University of
California, Berkeley. Earlier versions of this paper were presented at the NBER/NSF
```

This is in a completely different format from the form it is in during the pdf.

**Bonus:**
I had made a mistake with the example I had posted. If I copy and paste from a pdf document from google chrome, I would get that output. If I copy and paste from a Microsoft Edge, I would get something like:

```
Oil and the Macroeconomy since World War 11 
James D. Hamilton 
University (f/' Virgiiwa 
All but one of the U.S. recessions since World War II have been preceded, typically with a lag of around three-fourths of a year, by a dramatic increase in the price of crude petroleum. This does not mean that oil shocks caused these recessions. Evidence is presented, however, that even over the period 1948-72 this correlation is statis- tically significant and nonspurlious, supporting the proposition that oil shocks were a contributing factor in at least some of the U.S. recessions prior to 1972. By extension, energy price increases may account for much of post-OPEC macroeconomic performance. 
I. Introduction 
The poor performance of the U.S. economy since 1973 is well docu- mented: 1. The rate of growth of real GNP has fallen from an average of 4.0 percent during 1960-72 to 2.4 percent for 1973-81. 2. The 7.6 percent average inflation rate during 1973-81 was more than double the 3.1 percent realized for 1960-72. 3. The average unemployment rate over 1973-81 of 6.7 percent was higher than in any year between 1948 and 1972 with the single exception of the recession of 1958. 
This paper is drawn from chap. 2 of my Ph.D. dissertation at the University of California, Berkeley. Earlier versions of this paper were presented at the NBER/NSF
```

Sorry for the mistake. The previous answer was valid for the question I was asking at the time, but this is the type of output I am trying to get.

Comment: I think you should show a real example of what happens when you copy and paste from a real .pdf file.

Comment: @Ista I added a real example. Is that basically what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the difference is just the presence/absence of white space at the beginning of each line. You can remove it in R using `gsub`. For example:

```
library(pdftools)
doc <- "https://www.researchgate.net/profile/James_Hamilton11/publication/24108242_Oil_and_the_Macroeconomy_since_World_War_II/links/0c9605252c0916e709000000.pdf"
text <- pdf_text(doc)[[3]]
text_no_ws <- gsub("^|\n +", "\n", text)
cat(text_no_ws)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had made a mistake in the output I had chosen to add. That was not what I had wanted. I updated my new question, with the desired output, under Bonus.